# get value using max(dict comprehension)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm storing values in a dict in this way:

```
def fname():
    return max({(x): x**2 for x in range(1, 20)})
```

The problem is this returns the value of max key, and i need the value of that key.

How the get the value or rewrite this so that i do get the value of the max key?
Preferably without the use of itertools.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, i would need this written in a single line.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. Are you actually using this dict? Why not `19**2`?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use dict comprehension if you don't use this dict? 
You can just write
max(x**2 for x in range(1, 20))

Answer (score 1):

you can get a list of the values in the dict

```
max({(x): x**2 for x in range(1, 20)}.values())
361
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is requested to print the value of largest key, we have to find the largest key.

```
l = sorted(list({x:x**2 for x in range(1, 20)}.items()), key = lambda v:v[0], reverse=True)[0][1]
print(l)
# 361
```

In the above example, largest value is also having largest key.
Hence let's solve by different example

```
d = {1:4,2:3}
l = sorted(list(d.items()), key = lambda v:v[0], reverse=True)[0][1]
print(l)
# 3
```

Note it prints 3 and not 4.